# Redmine 2.5.2 and Glassfish 4.1

Tags: windows, glassfish, jruby, redmine

I'm trying to get redmine 2.5.2 on Glassfish 4.1. Everything works just fine, using warble and creating and uploading the war file.

When I try to load the main page of Redmine ill get the following error:

```
An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup
you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar
load error: org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.47/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47  -java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream handler unavailable due to: null (LoadError)
```

The config I have atm:

```
--- System
jruby 1.7.16 (1.9.3p392) 2014-09-25 575b395 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_25-b17 +jit [Windows Server 2008 R2-amd64]
Time: 2014-10-15 16:12:42 +0200
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1 
jruby.home: file:/C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home

--- Context Init Parameters:
com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration = true
com.sun.faces.validateXml = true
public.root = /
rails.env = production

--- Backtrace
RuntimeError: 

    you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar

load error: org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.47/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47 -- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream handler unavailable due to: null (LoadError)
       do_require at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:202
      require_jar at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:151
      require_jar at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:211
           (root) at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/jopenssl/load.rb:9
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/openssl.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/openssl.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/net/https.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at /C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/net/https.rb:22
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/fetchers.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/fetchers.rb:6
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/kvpost.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/kvpost.rb:2
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
          require at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/consumer/idres.rb:1
             eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/consumer/idres.rb:3
             each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/consumer.rb:1
             load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid/consumer.rb:1
  load_dependency at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid.rb:1
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/ruby-openid-2.3.0/lib/openid.rb:19
             each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:1
    instance_exec at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1562
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:2
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/plugins/open_id_authentication/init.rb:1
             each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/lib/plugins/open_id_authentication/init.rb:5
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2
           (root) at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
             load at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245
             load at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245
           Engine at C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:593

--- RubyGems
Gem.dir: C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems
Gem.path:
C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems
Activated gems:
  bundler-1.7.3
  rake-10.1.1
  i18n-0.6.11
  multi_json-1.10.1
  activesupport-3.2.19
  builder-3.0.0
  activemodel-3.2.19
  erubis-2.7.0
  journey-1.0.4
  rack-1.4.5
  rack-cache-1.2
  rack-test-0.6.2
  hike-1.2.3
  tilt-1.4.1
  sprockets-2.2.2
  actionpack-3.2.19
  mime-types-1.25.1
  polyglot-0.3.5
  treetop-1.4.15
  mail-2.5.4
  actionmailer-3.2.19
  arel-3.0.3
  tzinfo-0.3.41
  activerecord-3.2.19
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.10
  jdbc-mysql-5.1.31
  activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter-1.3.10
  activeresource-3.2.19
  awesome_nested_set-2.1.6
  coderay-1.1.0
  fastercsv-1.5.5
  rack-ssl-1.3.4
  json-1.8.1-java
  rdoc-3.12.2
  thor-0.19.1
  railties-3.2.19
  jquery-rails-2.0.3
  net-ldap-0.3.1
  ruby-openid-2.3.0
  rack-openid-1.4.2
  rails-3.2.19

--- Bundler
Bundler.bundle_path: C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems
Bundler.root: C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF
Gemfile: C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\redmine-2.5.2\WEB-INF\Gemfile
Settings:
  gemfile = C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\redmine-2.5.2\WEB-INF\Gemfile
  without = development:test:assets
  bin_path = C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/redmine-2.5.2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.3/bin/bundle

--- JRuby-Rack Config
compat_version = 
default_logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.StandardOutLogger@4ec89072
equals = <error: >
err = org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadPrintStream@78e5fe5a
filter_adds_html = true
filter_verifies_resource = false
ignore_environment = false
initial_memory_buffer_size = 
initial_runtimes = 
jms_connection_factory = 
jms_jndi_properties = 
logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.ServletContextLogger@6f890d21
logger_class_name = servlet_context
logger_name = jruby.rack
maximum_memory_buffer_size = 
maximum_runtimes = 
num_initializer_threads = 
out = org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadPrintStream@36dc2360
rackup = 
rackup_path = 
rewindable = true
runtime_arguments = 
runtime_environment = 
runtime_timeout_seconds = 
serial_initialization = false
servlet_context = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@1eb8631a
throw_init_exception = false
```

The gems on the machine:

```
actionmailer (3.2.19)
actionpack (3.2.19)
activemodel (4.1.6, 3.2.19)
activerecord (4.1.6, 3.2.19)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.10)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.3.10)
activeresource (3.2.19)
activesupport (4.1.6, 3.2.19)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214, 3.0.3)
awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
axiom-types (0.1.1)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.7.3)
coderay (1.1.0)
coercible (1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
equalizer (0.0.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3 java)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.9.3 java)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.11)
ice_nine (0.11.0)
jar-dependencies (0.1.2)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.31)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.3)
jruby-jars (1.7.16)
jruby-openssl (0.9.5 java)
jruby-rack (1.1.16)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
json (1.8.1 java, 1.8.0 java)
krypt (0.0.2)
krypt-core (0.0.2 universal-java)
krypt-provider-jdk (0.0.2)
mail (2.5.4)
maven-tools (1.0.5)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (5.4.2)
multi_json (1.10.1)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.4.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.19)
railties (3.2.19)
rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0)
rdoc (4.0.1, 3.12.2)
ruby-maven (3.1.1.0.8)
ruby-maven-libs (3.1.1)
ruby-openid (2.3.0)
rubyzip (1.1.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4 java)
tilt (1.4.1)
tin (1.0.2)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.41)
virtus (1.0.3)
warbler (1.4.4)
```

Someone have the same problem? I can't get it to work, hope you guys can help me!